# How can I compare sorting methods? Ram usage, Time taken

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I have a science fair project I am doing this year and I wanted to do something with computers. I decided to take multiple sorting algorithms (Insertion, selection and bubble) and compare how long they take to sort data and how much ram they used doing it.

I was wondering how can I look at how long it takes to sort and how much ram is used? Is there a program that will do this for me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C/C++, you can use valgrind 
http://valgrind.org/

Many other languages have profiling tools as well, what language are you planning to use for this.